# When should I write to EEPROM?

Tags: arduino, eeprom, wear-leveling

I built a simple project using an arduino to control a I2C digital potentiometer being controlled by a remote control via a IR Detector. The purpose is to be able to control the input signal of a audio amp using a remote control. It works just fine, but at the point I set the power up volume to default at -49dB.

But I thought in using the internal EEPROM to hold the volume between power cycles. But my question is when should I write to the EEPROM? Because I don't have a power down signal, and I don't want to write on every key press, because someone can change the volume a lot in a day.

Should I set a counter variable and watch for changes like every 30 seconds or so, and write to the EEPROM?

The value I want to store is a uint8_t.

I'm very new to the field, so I'm looking for any clever tricks.

Comment: Why not use a diode, capacitor, and the internal analog comparator to detect power fail?

Comment: @Ignacio could you explain it better, maybe post an answer. I'm open to any kind of path.

Answer (score 4):

The ATmega328 data sheet, in section "8.4 EEPROM Data Memory" says
The EEPROM has an endurance of at least 100,000 write/erase cycles

So a reasonable strategy should be okay.

1. Wait at least 30+ seconds after the last change, *before* considering a write. When I futz with the volume, it is to mute advertising. Also I often increase volume to hear something specific, maybe a favourite track, then re-set volume quite close to where I started. If you haven't implemented a mute, it might be worth doing so. That is a common case for me, and might be a common case for you. You might significantly reduce the number of volume updates by ignoring mute, and leaving the saved volume unchanged.
2. Don't write if the value is only a couple of % different. It is unlikely that your ears will tell the difference.

If the number of writes/day is still an issue, detect 'power down', and change the strategy to only saving when power is being removed.

The chip will need several milliseconds to ensure it can do the EEPROM write. 
The best data I've found about EEPROM write time is "Table 28-18, Typical Wait Delay Before Writing the Next Flash or EEPROM Location" says the delay is "3.6ms".

So the local power supply to the ATmega will need a maintain an operating voltage for longer than that to ensure EEPROM is correctly written. That might be a bit awkward to do on an Arduino. IIRC the power supply capacitance within the power supply is about 100uF, which is marginal, and probably too little to be sure of doing the write, especially if any significant loads were being driven at the same time.

Comment: I do have a mute feature, and I will probably don't save it, because powering up on mute could be confusing to some people. But I haven't decided yet a approach. I'm thinking in implementing some sort of standby, because at the moment I just have a hard switch.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need all those EEPROM bytes for anything else, you can also take a systematic approach to wear leveling rather than trying to reduce the wear on a single EEPROM location.

See, for example, [this AVR application note](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2526.pdf) which uses two circular buffers. If you want to protect ears you might also want to store a checksum or CRC to protect against corrupted data.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the user experience you want to create. If you turn the stereo on early Monday morning, and it's still set to "11" from Saturday's party, you're going to have a bad time.

Consider making the "restore volume to last saved value" something that the *user* decides. An additional button or two on your remote could handle "save current volume setting" and "use saved volume" duties. Then have the system come up to a (low) default setting at power-on.

This is, I think, the most efficient way to maximize the EEPROM life.

So, save the volume setting, and restore it, ***only when the user demands it***.

Comment: Respectively disagree, all physical volume controls, plus ones whose settings are stored in EEPROM that I know of always power up with the last setting.  So that is what the user will expect.  With electronic pots, the system may start up with a lower setting to avoid jarring the user before ramping up to the previous setting.

Comment: I think sound level is a special case here. Weigh the risk of annoying the user (high) with the potential for pleasing the user (low) when the volume comes back to the previous setting. Other types of controls (EQ, radio station presets, etc.) don't have such an unfavorable risk:reward ratio so should clearly persist between power cycles.

Compromise solution: only store in EEPROM levels below a certain threshold.

Comment: I will take back something I said in my original comment (since I can't edit my comment after so many minutes).  Old style electrical pots, which have an on/off switch in the counter-clockwise position, do behave as you are suggesting, since you always have to turn the volume all the way down to turn the radio off.  It's only newer ones, with a push-on push-off on/off switch that retain their volume setting.

Comment: I though about this, maybe I should not turn it above 50% on power up even if the volume was last set to full. Or something like that.

Comment: I just thought about implementing a standby mode, so I could add a relay to to turn it off and use that event to write. My main issue is that the amp have a hard switch and I'm tapping off its power supply, a standby would be nice but require me to add a second always-on power supply.